# Five circles aligned , and when i click on the circle i would like the number 5 to appear inside the circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, geometry

I'm trying to have five circles aligned, and then when I click on the circle, I want the number 5 to appear inside the circle, and if I click again the number 4 appears instead of the number 5 etc. some kind of counter.

I drew the circles using CSS and tried using jQuery to manipulate the circles and have the numbers appear but I didn't have the desired result.

When I click on the circle, the number 5 appears but the circle get displaced. Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

[Here is my Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j8j3j0fv/)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Circle clicking </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width , initial-scale = 1.0">
    <body class: "body">
    <div id="first-exercise">       
        <h4 id="left">squat</h4>
        <h4 id="right">5x5 100LB</h4>
        <hr width="95%">
        <p class="circle"></p>
        <p class="circle2"></p>
        <p class="circle3"></p>
        <p class="circle4"></p>
        <p class="circle5"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#first-exercise {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width:60%; 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 8%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 7px #777777;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #777777;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.circle {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #f91d04;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: lightgray;
}

.circle2 {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: lightgray;
}

.circle3{
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: lightgray;
}

.circle4 {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: lightgray;
}
.circle5 {
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: lightgray;
}
#first-exercise p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 0%;
}

#first-exercise h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: #f91d04;
}
#first-exercise #right{
    margin: 0% 2% 0% 61%;
}

#first-exercise #left{
    margin: 0% 14% 0% 2%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#first-exercise .circle').on('click', function(){
   $('#first-exercise .circle').html('<p>5<p>')  
});
```

Comment: If you want a valid and complete answer please add the Code to the question CSS -- HTML -- JQUERY

Comment: Can you share some code (or even a screenshot) to help with diagnosing the problem. Thanks

Comment: "I’m trying to have five circles aligned, and then when i click on the circle" - which circle?

Comment: Here's a non-javascript approach using CSS counters : http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/pvgcjdje/

Comment: Why do you give the `body` element class `body`? btw. correct definition is `<body class="body">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took the liberty to change your CSS.

I think this is probably what you intended:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title> New Responsive design web page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport"    content= "width=device-width , initial-scale = 1.0">


    <style>
        #first-exercise{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width:60%;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 8%;

            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #777777;
            -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0px 7px #777777;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #777777;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

        }

        .circle {
            width: 34px;
            height: 34px;
            background: #fff;
            -moz-border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            border-color: lightgray;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 34px;
        }

        .circle.selected {
            background: #f91d04;
        }

        #first-exercise p {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 10%;
            margin-top: 0%;
            margin-bottom: 1%;
        }

        #first-exercise h4 {
            display: inline-block;
            font-variant: small-caps;
            color: #f91d04;

        }
        #first-exercise #right{
            margin: 0% 2% 0% 61%;

        }

        #first-exercise #left{
            margin: 0% 14% 0% 2%;
        }


    </style>


<body>
<div id="first-exercise">

    <h4 id="left">squat</h4>
    <h4 id="right">5x5 100LB</h4>
    <hr width="95%">
    <p class="circle">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="circle">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="circle">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="circle">&nbsp;</p>
    <p class="circle">&nbsp;</p>




</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
// init array
var counter = [];
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) counter[i] = 5;

$('#first-exercise .circle').on('click', function(){

    var index = $('#first-exercise .circle').index(this);

    var displayText = counter[index];
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).html(displayText);

    if (counter[index] == 0)
    {
        counter[index] = 5;
    }
    else {
        counter[index]-=1;
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you , this is much better than what i did.

but  what if i want it to be like a counter .

when i click the first time an ( X ) would appear.

If i click a second time a ( 5 ) appears , and if i click again a ( 4 ) appears ... etc

Comment: Updated example with counter.  Please modify as appropriate

Comment: it's good , but this technique considers all the circle as being one. that is why i created five different circles .
Can i have five different circles in the CSS , so that they behave separately ?
Should i use a loop, because i want it to stop at 0 , and then if i click again it writes an (X) and then (5) ..etc. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: How can i stop the counter at 0 and make it start again from 5 ?

Comment: You can use an array to keep track of the counter and jquery index() to check the index of the circle being clicked.  See updated sample.

Comment: Thank you , Why when i click for example when it's "5" it becomes an empty circle, and then i have to press again in order for number "4" to appear . 
Another question:  what if i wanted the counter to start a "5" and not "x" .

Comment: Thanks , it helped me a lot and i'm going to tinker it to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***JavaScript***. Create a `<div id="(add your id here)">` element covering the circle and use CSS to re-shape it to the circle's size and shape. Make a JavaScript script implemented in the HTML document and use the `document.getElementById()` method to assign a variable to the element. Now use the `variable.innerHTML` variable and set it to the **Integer** "5" as default. When the circle gets clicked, insert a statement to decrease the variable `variable.innerHTML` by one. To make the text change to 5 when the circle is clicked and it is 0, just add a statement in the *circle_clicked event handler* to do that. The code for that statement is as follows:

```
if (variable.innerHTML === 0) {
    variable.innerHTML = 5;
}
```

Hope this Helps.